# Commodore 64c supply 9 Vac waveform specs

Tags: commodore-64, power

I found an old Commodore 64c without a box, cable, or anything else and I want to put it back to work.

In order to do so, I need to turn it on to see if it works. I've already found the pinout of the power port but I don't know some characteristics of the 9 Vac supply waveform. These unknowns are the frequency, the waveform type and if it stays positive or goes positive and negative. I have the European version.

Does anyone know this information?

Comment: I would be astonished if that was anything other than a nominal 9V tap off the mains transformer. So, _approximately_ a 9V RMS sine wave at 49–61Hz.

Comment: With or without the negative edge?

Comment: @jack07Code Well, if it's AC, then it would have negative as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn depends on how you define zero and how many pins you have. Floating, one or other side referenced to ground, or even a midpoint referenced to ground are possible. (All of these are used for mains sockets in different scenarios,  though floating is rare)

Comment: @user1937198 Seams you're mixing up the nature of [Alternating Current (AC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current) with voltage measurement. You're right that voltage is a reference based value, but direction of current is not. It's either or. If it does not change (on a regular base) it's DC, otherwise it's AC. That's why an AC system inherently has a mid point. And while AC can be measured as Peak-to-Peak, it rarely is. Nominal voltage for AC is  always given as RMS, based on that mid point. (Gedankenexperiment: describe the workings of a diode bridge without changing direction)

Comment: @Raffzahn For electrical current transfer yes. For safety, no. For safety, protective earth is absolutely defined as 'ground reference'. It is essential to be clear as to what the expectations are of reference to protective earth, due to the amount of electrical equipment that either directly or capacitively couples its supply 'neutral' to the case.

Comment: @user1937198 you're going even further afar by assuming non related items. The question asks about 9VAC - which is a a complete description in itself. Also there is no reference to 'PE' of any kind nor has to be one. Please stay serious.

Comment: @user1937198, the 9 Vac output is just the two wires from the transformer coil, isolated from anything else. So one terminal (call it B) will have to be used as a reference if you're going to measure the voltage at the other (call it A). And when you do, you'll see a sine wave going positive and negative - plain old 9 Vac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 9VAC is just 9VAC out of a 9VAC transformer secondary. Sine wave. 50 Hz since you have an european C64.

Comment: It ought not to have a ground connection; typical schematic here <https://pdbuchan.com/commodore/c64_power_supply/c64_external_power_supply_902503-02.png>